# Drupal 7 - Switching between Templates for Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, drupal

I come from a Wordpress background and i'm trying to wrap my head around content-types and templates.

My issue is that if I have 2 pages which are slightly different in layout, let's call one 'Wide' and one 'Narrow' then I need a content type for both. But if I change my mind and want 'Narrow' to be 'Wide' as well then I need to delete the page and re-add it as the other content type.. which seems very long winded.

In wordpress you build you templates and then assign each page to a template, and if you don't then it defaults to the default template (which in drupal would just be page.tpl.php) I'm just wondering whether there is anything similar in Drupal?

Thanks for any help
Dan

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a module called Display Suite https://drupal.org/project/ds

If used in conjunction with other modules such as Context or Panels you can create multiple templates and then assign them by Node type, URL etc